# .net WebApi 2.0 - Set culture for all the user request at code level (Globalization)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, globalization

I have a .net webapi 2.0 using standard .Net Framework ( not core ).

In this moment the default Culture is set in webconfig:

## web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="it-IT" culture="it-IT" />
  </system.web>
```

What I wan't to do Is provide a method where the user can switch the culture.
I'm trying this code but it doesn't work...

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(strCulture);
```

The culture is changed only for that thread but for the nexts it continues to get the default culture specified in webconfig....

Thanks to support

Comment: add this code too :  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(strCulture);   also see https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/27/Auto-Selecting-Cultures-for-Localization-in-ASPNET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
public class LanguageMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // here you can chose to get the lang from database, cookie or from the request if the culture is stored on local storage.
        SetCulture(request, "ro-RO");
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void SetCulture(HttpRequestMessage request, string lang)
    {
        request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Clear();
        request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue(lang));
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
    }
}
```

Add the LanguageMessageHandler to MessageHandlers in WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new LanguageMessageHandler()); // <- add this line
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```